# How to customize buddypress groups

Tags: php, css, customization, buddypress

I am setting a Wordpress page and I am trying to customize the appearance of buddypress groups. I want them to appear horizontally instead of vertically. Could anyone guide me through?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="groups-list" class="item-list" role="main"></div>

            <?php while ( bp_groups() ) : bp_the_group(); ?>

            <?php bp_group_class(); ?>
        <div class="item-avatar">
            <a href="<?php bp_group_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_group_avatar( 'type=thumb&width=50&height=50' ); ?></a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title"><a href="<?php bp_group_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_group_name(); ?></a></div>
            <div class="item-meta"><span class="activity"><?php printf( __( 'active %s', 'buddypress' ), bp_get_group_last_active() ); ?></span></div>

            <div class="item-desc"><?php bp_group_description_excerpt(); ?></div>

            <?php do_action( 'bp_directory_groups_item' ); ?>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wrap the result of the loop inside div and float it? I think with css you will be fine as long as you clear the floats after. Something like this:

```
<div class="group-container">
<?php while ( bp_groups() ) : bp_the_group(); ?>

<?php bp_group_class(); ?>
    <div class="float-left">
    <div class="item-avatar">
        <a href="<?php bp_group_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_group_avatar( 'type=thumb&width=50&height=50' ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-title"><a href="<?php bp_group_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_group_name(); ?></a></div>
        <div class="item-meta"><span class="activity"><?php printf( __( 'active %s', 'buddypress' ), bp_get_group_last_active() ); ?></span></div>
        <div class="item-desc"><?php bp_group_description_excerpt(); ?></div>

        <?php do_action( 'bp_directory_groups_item' ); ?>

    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="clear-floats"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to add bootstrap class you will have to add the row class outside the loop (that goes through the groups) and then add the the col class inside the loop for each group. But I think you will have to wrap all this inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * The bp_is_active( 'groups' ) check is recommended, to prevent problems 
 * during upgrade or when the Groups component is disabled
 */
if ( bp_is_active( 'groups' ) ) :
 
class Group_Extension_Example_1 extends BP_Group_Extension {
    /**
     * Your __construct() method will contain configuration options for 
     * your extension, and will pass them to parent::init()
     */
    function __construct() {
        $args = array(
            'slug' => 'group-extension-example-1',
            'name' => 'Group Extension Example 1',
        );
        parent::init( $args );
    }
 
    /**
     * display() contains the markup that will be displayed on the main 
     * plugin tab
     */
    function display( $group_id = NULL ) {
        $group_id = bp_get_group_id();
        echo 'What a cool plugin!';
    }
 
    /**
     * settings_screen() is the catch-all method for displaying the content 
     * of the edit, create, and Dashboard admin panels
     */
    function settings_screen( $group_id = NULL ) {
        $setting = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, 'group_extension_example_1_setting' );
 
        ?>
        Save your plugin setting here: <input type="text" name="group_extension_example_1_setting" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $setting ) ?>" />
        <?php
    }
 
    /**
     * settings_sceren_save() contains the catch-all logic for saving 
     * settings from the edit, create, and Dashboard admin panels
     */
    function settings_screen_save( $group_id = NULL ) {
        $setting = '';
 
        if ( isset( $_POST['group_extension_example_1_setting'] ) ) {
            $setting = $_POST['group_extension_example_1_setting'];
        }
 
        groups_update_groupmeta( $group_id, 'group_extension_example_1_setting', $setting );
    }
}
bp_register_group_extension( 'Group_Extension_Example_1' );
 
endif; // if ( bp_is_active( 'groups' ) )
```